# Script reenvio respuestas en formulario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

he creado un formulario que me gustaría que cuando sea cumplimentado por un usuario a este le llegue un mail con el resumen de sus respuestas.

Mi problema es que no se como indicarle que envie los datos de la última fila de la hoja de respuestas. Si le defino la columna y fila me funciona de manera correcta.

Os pego el código que estoy usando:

```
function onFormSubmit (e) {

    // Definimos las variables
    var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("a2").getValue();
    var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("b2").getValue();
    var dni = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("c2").getValue();
    var mail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("f2").getValue();
    var prueba = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("e2").getValue();
    var data_prueba = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("g2").getValue();

    // Asunto
    var subject = "Tu solicitud ha quedado registrada " + prueba;

    // emailBody en texto plano
    var emailBody = "Este es un mail de prueba para el usuario " + name + 
                    "\nFrom " + data + 
                    "\nFrom " + dni + 
                    "\nFrom " + mail + 
                    "\nWith email " + prueba + 
                    "\nRegister on " + data_prueba +
                    "\nMuchas gracias por tu registro!"; 

    // More info for Advanced Options Parameters 
    var advancedOpts = { Nombre: "xxxx", htmlBody: htmlBody };

    // Instrucciones envio mail
    MailApp.sendEmail(mail, subject, emailBody, advancedOpts);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El objeto evento del activador "Form Submit" incluye varias propiedades que te podrían servir:

- `namedValues`: Un objeto incluyendo los nombres de las preguntas y las respuestas
- `range`: Un objeto Range representando la celda o intervalo editados
- `values`: Un Array de los valores en el mismo orden en el que aparecen en la hoja de cálculo

Si tu objeto evento es `e` en tu código usa `e.range` para llamar el objeto Range.

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado añadiendo la linea:

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Podrias , explicar como has llegado a esa solucion y poner donde has cambiado  la linea para que la respuesta no quede asi tan simplona :)

Comment: getLastRow() no es del todo confiable porque la hoja de cálculo este método, si no se han tomado la medidas apropiadas, podría devolver el mismo valor a dos instancias de ejecución diferentes y una instancias podría sobre escribir los datos de la otra. Esto sólo sería problema si se presentara el caso de que dos usuarios diferentes enviaran una respuesta de formulario prácticamente al mismo tiempo.